# What documentation exists for DynamoDB's consistency model, CAP, partition recovery etc?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm considering using Amazon's DynamoDB. Naturally, if you're bothering to use a highly available distributed data store, you want to make sure your client deals with outages in a sensible way!

While I can find documentation describing Amazon's "Dynamo" database, it's my understanding that "DynamoDB" [derives its name from Dynamo, but is not at all related in any other way](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dynamo_%28storage_system%29&oldid=607941330).

For DynamoDB itself, the only documentation I can find is a [brief forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=466349) which basically says "retry 500 errors". For most other databases much more detailed information is available.

Where should I be looking to learn more about DynamoDB's outage handling?

Answer (score 11):

While [Amazon DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) indeed lacks a detailed statement about their choices regarding the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) (still hoping for a DynamoDB edition of Kyle Kingsbury's most excellent [Jepsen](http://aphyr.com/tags/Jepsen) series - [Call me maybe: Cassandra](http://aphyr.com/posts/294-call-me-maybe-cassandra) analyzes a Dynamo inspired database), Jeff Walker Code Ranger's answer to [DynamoDB: Conditional writes vs. the CAP theorem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23371813/45773) confirms the *lack of clear information in this area*, but asserts that we *can make some pretty strong inferences*.

The referenced [forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=466349) also suggests a strong emphasis on availability too in fact:

> DynamoDB does indeed synchronously replicate across multiple
>   availability zones within the region, and is therefore tolerant to a
>   zone failure. If a zone becomes unavailable, you will still be able to
>   use DynamoDB and the service will persist any successful writes that
>   we have acknowledged (including writes we acknowledged at the time
>   that the availability zone became unavailable).
>
> The customer experience when a complete availability zone is lost
>   ranges from no impact at all to delayed processing times in cases
>   where failure detection and service-side redirection are necessary.
>   The exact effects in the latter case depend on whether the customer
>   uses the service's API directly or connects through one of our SDKs.

Other than that, Werner Vogels' posts on Dynamo/DynamoDB provide more insight eventually:

- [Amazon's Dynamo](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/10/amazons_dynamo.html) - about the original paper
- [Amazon DynamoDB – a Fast and Scalable NoSQL Database Service Designed for Internet Scale Applications](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2012/01/amazon-dynamodb.html) - main introductory article including:

  - *History of NoSQL at Amazon – Dynamo*
  - *Lessons learned from Amazon's Dynamo*
  - *Introducing DynamoDB* - this features the most relevant information regarding the subject matter

    > **Durable and Highly Available**. Amazon DynamoDB replicates its data over
    >   at least 3 different data centers so that the system can continue to
    >   operate and serve data even under complex failure scenarios.
    >
    > **Flexible**. Amazon DynamoDB is an extremely flexible system that does
    >   not force its users into a particular data model or a particular
    >   consistency model. DynamoDB tables do not have a fixed schema but
    >   instead allow each data item to have any number of attributes,
    >   including multi-valued attributes. **Developers can optionally use
    >   stronger consistency models when accessing the database, trading off
    >   some performance and availability for a simpler model**. They can also
    >   take advantage of the atomic increment/decrement functionality of
    >   DynamoDB for counters. *[emphasis mine]*
- [DynamoDB One Year Later: Bigger, Better, and 85% Cheaper…](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2013/03/dynamodb-one-year-later.html) - about improvements

Finally, Aditya Dasgupta's presentation about [Amazon's Dynamo DB](https://wiki.cites.illinois.edu/wiki/display/cs598rco/Aditya+Dasgupta) also analyzes its modus operandi regarding the CAP theorem.

#### Practical Guidance

In terms of practical guidance for retry handling, the DynamoDB team has meanwhile added a dedicated section about [Handling Errors](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ErrorHandling.html), including [Error Retries and Exponential Backoff](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ErrorHandling.html#APIRetries).

Comment: Aditya Dasgupta's presentation seems mis-titled, it's actually about  the earlier *Dynamo*, not *Dynamo DB*.